# After an ORDER BY get the first item in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, min

I'm using a GROUP BY to display general info from a table.

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY Continent
```

Datas are the following ones:

```
|--------|-----------|-----------|
| Id     | Continent |    Fruits |
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|      1 |    Africa |    Banana |
|      1 |    Africa |    Cherry |
|      1 |    Mexico |     Apple |
|      1 |    Mexico |      Pear |
|      1 |    Europa | Blueberry |
|      1 |    Europa |    Orange |
|      1 |    Europa |      Kiwi |
|--------|-----------|-----------|
```

Now how can I get the FIRST fruit from each continent ?

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT *, MIN(Fruits) AS FirstFruit FROM table GROUP BY Continent
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want two columns in the resultset, then aggregation is sufficient:

```
select continent, min(fruits) as firstfruit 
from mytable 
group by continent
```

If, on the other hand, there are other columns you are interested it, then aggregation alone cannot give you the result you want. One option uses a correlated subquery to filter the table:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.fruits = (select min(t1.fruits) from mytable t1 where t1.continent = t.continent)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I then return the number of rows hold in the GROUP BY please?

Comment: @Gepeto: that's pretty basic SQL, really. Just add `count(*)` to the `select` clause of the first query.